# post hoc tests in ANOVA

Tags: anova, bonferroni

While I am doing post hoc test for one way ANOVA, I am getting significant results for LSD but the same variables does not have significant values for Bonferroni. Why is it so?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by LSD, and exactly what are you testing.

Comment: LSD I believe is Fisher's Least Significant Difference. I am testing the effect of three kinds of shift work on memory function. My impact of shift work is significant on memory function while I am doing ANOVA but when I am doing Bonferroni no significant difference is found but in case of LSD there is a significant difference. I am a bit confused!!!

Answer (score 2):

Bonferroni adjusts For Type I error rates. LSD does not.  With more post hoc comparisons, more are likely to be significant using LSD. If making more than 3 pairwise comparisons, don't use LSD.  I recommend HSD (Tukey) in SPSS if homogeneity of variances is not violated.  Bonferroni is very conservative.